# Compile error with simple Swift extension on NSObject

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a set of extensions that make dealing with JSON objects simpler in swift.  Here is a sample of the extension code I have set up:

```
import Foundation

extension NSData {
    var JSONObject: AnyObject? {
        return parseJSONObject(self)
    }
}

extension String {
    var JSONObject: AnyObject? {
        return self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding).JSONObject
    }
}

func parseJSONObject(object: NSData) -> AnyObject? {
    var error: NSError?
    var result : AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(object as NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error)

    if error {
        println("Error parsing JSON object from: \(object)");
    }

    return result
}
```

This code works when I use it for String objects, but it does not work on NSData objects external to this file.  The strange part is that the String extension calls the NSData extension code and works fine from within the file.  Does anyone know what the problem may be?

```
import XCTest

let testJSONString = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"

class JSONTests: XCTestCase {
    let testJSONData = testJSONString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    // This test compiles with no problem, as I am using the extension on a Swift String.
    func testParseString() {
        var fooValue: String? = testJSONString.JSONObject!["foo"] as? String
        XCTAssertTrue(fooValue == "bar", "Value for key 'foo' should be 'bar' for parsed JSON string")
    }

    // This method causes a compiler error I assume, because I am using the NSData extension
    func testParseData() {
        var fooValue: String? = testJSONData.JSONObject!["foo"] as? String
        XCTAssertTrue(fooValue == "bar", "Value for key 'foo' should be 'bar' for parsed JSON string")
    }
}
```

Here is the error that I am seeing:

```
CompileSwift normal i386 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    cd /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -target i386-apple-ios8.0 -module-name SwiftKitTests -O0 -sdk /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -g -module-cache-path /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -I /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -c -j8 /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/SwiftKit/Application/PlanckTags.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/Belt/JSON.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/SwiftKitTests/Belt/JSONTests.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/Planck/Planck.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/Belt/RingBuffer.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/SwiftKitTests/Planck/PlanckTests.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/SwiftKitTests/Belt/RingBufferTests.swift -output-file-map /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/SwiftKitTests-OutputFileMap.json -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/SwiftKitTests.swiftmodule -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/SwiftKitTests-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/SwiftKitTests-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/SwiftKitTests-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/SwiftKitTests-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/DerivedSources/i386 -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/SwiftKitTests-Swift.h

0  swift                    0x000000010c4c0608 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x000000010c4c0af4 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff914b25aa _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000000000004 _sigtramp + 1857346164
4  swift                    0x000000010b8c47b2 swift::irgen::emitVirtualMethodValue(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, llvm::Value*, swift::SILType, swift::SILDeclRef, swift::CanTypeWrapper<swift::SILFunctionType>, swift::ResilienceExpansion) + 434
5  swift                    0x000000010b9300d3 swift::SILVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction, void>::visit(swift::ValueBase*) + 42611
6  swift                    0x000000010b925266 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 8678
7  swift                    0x000000010b8a66f8 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitGlobalTopLevel() + 184
8  swift                    0x000000010b9126e3 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::Module*, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 1859
9  swift                    0x000000010b913033 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::SourceFile&, swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&, unsigned int) + 51
10 swift                    0x000000010b88565a frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 4842
11 swift                    0x000000010b88435d main + 1533
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff8d5c55fd start + 1
13 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000042 start + 1923328582
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/SwiftKit/Application/PlanckTags.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/Belt/JSON.swift -primary-file /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/SwiftKitTests/Belt/JSONTests.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/Planck/Planck.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/Belt/RingBuffer.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/SwiftKitTests/Planck/PlanckTests.swift /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/SwiftKitTests/Belt/RingBufferTests.swift -enable-objc-attr-requires-objc-module -target i386-apple-ios8.0 -module-name SwiftKitTests -sdk /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -I /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -g -module-cache-path /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/SwiftKitTests-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/SwiftKitTests-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/SwiftKitTests-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/SwiftKitTests-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/DerivedSources/i386 -Xcc -I/Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -emit-module-doc-path /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/JSONTests~partial.swiftdoc -O0 -emit-module-path /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/JSONTests~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/JSONTests.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/JSONTests.d -o /Users/phogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftKit-btmjklrksylmiohgevkkbihmktno/Build/Intermediates/SwiftKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftKitTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/JSONTests.o 
1.  While emitting IR SIL function @_TFC13SwiftKitTests9JSONTests13testParseDatafS0_FT_T_ for 'testParseData' at /Users/phogan/Software/BanDedo/SwiftKit/SwiftKitTests/Belt/JSONTests.swift:29:5
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me: the compiler should not segfault

Comment: Definitely file a radar with Apple!

Comment: Radar filed: 17286971

Comment: Any solution or workaround? I got the same problem and I don't know how to continue. Only have to wait for the bug fix of Apple?

Comment: @bagusflyer The radar is still open.  No progress yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have have run into a similar problem.

I have one Extension that takes in a NSString and returns NSData and another Extension that takes in NSData and returns NSData.  I can place the NSString extension anywhere in Xcode, it can be in an external file, next to a Class in an external file, ViewController, Main, App Delegate anywhere.  The same is not true for my NSData extension. It will only run when it is placed inside the AppDelegate.

I was planning on putting all the Extensions that I create in a separate file or in the same file as its related class. But now as a workaround the NSData ext has to live inside the App Delegate file.  I'll post some code later. Right now it's a not a huge deal, just an oddity.

```
// just runs in App Delegate
extension NSData {
    var sha256:NSData { return myCrypto().dataToSHA256(self) } 
}

// runs just in external swift file just fine.
extension String {
    var hexToBytes:NSData { return myCrypto().hexToBytes(self) }
}
```

you can use Pseudo code and it will the NSData will always error out if the extension is not in the App Delegate at root level.